# SaveChanges affect several repository

Tags: entity-framework

How can I do to call a unique SaveChanges to affect all changes in all repositories that I use?
Should I create a class that contains all repositories and a Save method?
What's the best way to do it?

---

I'm trying this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    Product Product = new Product() { Id = 1, Name = "test", Amount = 1 };

    if (_productService.Insert(Product))
    {
        context.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is called unit of work and it is generally wrapper class to your EF context which is passed to constructor of your repositories. You than call `Save` on this new class.

Comment: So I need to create a instance of Entitie(inherited from DbContext), pass it to a repository and then call entitie.SaveChanges?

Comment: No you call save changes outside of the repository. Repository is not responsible for saving data, it is responsibility of the new context wrapper.

Comment: I update the problem's description.. can you tell me if this is right?

Comment: I need some validations before insert.. so I create a service layer passing the context to constructor.

Comment: @Peri: Yes [context is unit of work and DbSet / ObjectSet is repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625746/generic-repository-with-ef-4-1-what-is-the-point/5626884#5626884).

Answer (score 0):

Pass IDbContext/ObjectContext to constructor of your repositories. Work with repositories and call Save on context not on repository.

I would also rethink if You need repositories at all.

Comment: Yeah, I see Ladislav saying that repository isn't good.. I need some validations before save data.. so, what about I use only a service layer and inside it I call IDbContext methods? is this good?