# Unit of Work and Repository in > EF 4.1

Tags: wcf, silverlight, entity-framework, ria

Do I still need UoW/Repository Pattern in EF 4.1. It seems that the interfaces that the DbDomainContext provides already gives me a UoW/Repository pattern. I've seen some blogs also that they don't like Repository pattern either nor UoW but still made it testable.

Comment: This is closely related to [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625746/generic-repository-with-ef-4-1-what-is-the-point/5626884#5626884) without WCF RIA services. The answer to this question will be same if you plan to use generic repository and wrap context to UoW.

Comment: Hi Ladislav, I came across your answer before thanks for sharing the link. Will ask question now on your answer there.