# Entity Framework as UnitOfWork/Repository?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-of-work

I'm in the process of learning Entity Framework/MVC 4, and started following some tutorials on creating Repositories and abstracting away EF.

What I've noticed is that EF seems to already be a UnitOfWork/Repository pattern.

I tried creating custom DbSets by using `DbSet<TEntity>` as a base class, but couldn't get it to work because of the following exception: `The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TEntity>' has no constructors defined`.

Here's what I'm attempting to do:

```
public class RolesDbSet : DbSet<Role>
{
    public bool IsNameInUse(string name, int id = 0)
    {
        if (id == 0)
            return this.Any(r => r.Name == name);
        return this.Any(r => r.Name == name && r.ID != id);
    }
}

public class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyEntities() : base("MyEntities")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MyDevelopmentInitializer());
    }       

    public RolesDbSet Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Password> Passwords { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Then I would be able do do this:

```
bool inUse;
using (var db = new MyEntities())
{
    inUse = db.Roles.IsNameInUse("Employee");
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes [EF already implements repository and unit of work patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625746/generic-repository-with-ef-4-1-what-is-the-point).

You cannot create derived `DbSet<T>` because it doesn't have public nor protected constructor. The  only way is to implement `IDbSet<T>` directly and that is too complex. But instead of using instance  methods you can in the same way use extension methods and it will just work:

```
public static class RoleExtensions 
{
    public static bool IsNameInUse(this IQueryable<Role> query, string name, int id = 0)
    {
        if (id == 0)
            return query.Any(r => r.Name == name);
        return query.Any(r => r.Name == name && r.ID != id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great idea on using Extension methods! I use them for almost everything else, not sure why I didn't think of using them here.