# C# Generic Interfaces whitelist candidates filtering

Tags: c#, generics

I am very much new to Generics and found it very helpful in case Repository creation.
My question must be very basic level.

Suppose, I have declared a Generic interface something like

```
public interface IEFRepository<T> where T : class
{
    int Count { get; }
    bool Contains(T entity);
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    IQueryable<T> GetAll(string includeEntities);
    IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string includeEntities = "");
    T Add(T entity);
    T GetById(int id);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    int ExecuteSQL(string commandText);
    void Delete(int id);
}
```

Now, I can pass any class that implements this contract.
But I want to restrict it from being inherited by Only white list Classes that is configured in my Config file

eg. "Person | Department | Employee" are allowed.

Comment: Generics are compile time constructs. You can't create constraints, which are base on run-time data (config file)

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625746/generic-repository-with-ef-4-1-what-is-the-point

Comment: @Dipal Mehta: Which Main function are you using? in Main.cs or in Program.cs?

Comment: so you can try use [t4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should restrict your T classes belonging to a specific type, lets say an interface `IEntity`. Then your declaration would be:

```
public interface IEFRepository<T> where T : IEntity
```

Then you would declare your respective classes (`Person`, `Department` etc) to implement `IEntity` interface. This is far better solution because it gives you a **strongly typed** structure and protects you from **runtime errors**. Reading from app.config could easily lead you to runtime errors. Since you are implementing the repository pattern, perhaps you should read [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) very informative post regarding the [repository](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) and the unit of work patterns implemented using entity framework.

If you want to change the classes being entities in a dynamic way (without having to recompile your code) you could use [reflection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do so. **This is far more complicated and I would not suggest it but you know your project's requirements**. By using reflection, you would be able to read the configuration file and instantiate the respective classes directly, without needing them to implement interfaces or declaring their relation with the repositories in your code. Interfaces and inheritance give you **compile time consistency**, while **configuration options give you runtime choices**. I would prefer the first. You choose...

Hope I helped!

Comment: Is there any way to do Dynamic configurable composition?

Answer (score 5):

You can use constrains on Type Parameters, for example, restricting it to just classes that inherits from another one.

```
public interface IEFRepository<T>  where T : MyBaseClass
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: +1 for a useful technique, though in context of the original question, this is turtles all the way down (e.g., "how do I prevent a class from subclassing `MyBaseClass`").

Comment: Question was `But I want to restrict it from being inherited by Only white list Classes that is configured in my Config file`, which can't be done. Please, add some note regarding this requirements, by saying all models (Person, Department, Employee) should derive from `MyBaseClass`

Comment: Yes, Constraints can be useful but seems hard coded. Some handle is needed to represent pattern as White listed classes