# Resolving complex object graph with Unity

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, unity-container, dbcontext

I have the following situation, arrows represent dependencies:

[image: Hierarchy]

How can I resolve an Entity Manager object? When I resolve one, it creates 2 instances of the customer and address repository, but these instances need the same Dbcontext!

But I do not want the Dbcontext to be static in the entire application, when resolving another entity manager, it should resolve a separate dbcontext...

Comment: The best approach would be to remove the repository layer and query the context directly. This sounds controversial, but it isn't.

Comment: I'm not convinced. I'm open to the idea, but could you argument that?

Comment: Start here for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5625746/861716

Comment: PerResolveLifetimeManager was created for this situation. Why complicate things with child containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register you Dbcontext in Unity with [HierarchicalLifetimeManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx),  create new child container and resolve Entity Manager from new child container. So, you will have new instance of Dbcontext for every Entity Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `PerResolveLifetimeManager` for `DBContext` could help you.

All objects in graph has the same instance but a new instance is created in every graph resolve.

Full example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j5ciDJ).