# Working with entity framework, preferred way?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, coding-style

Suppose we have created Entities model, what is preferred way to work with it? I'm personally couldn't make up my mind..

1. Using ModelAdapter :

   ```
   public statiс Product[] GetProducts()
   {
           using(Entities ctx = new Entities())
           {
                   return ctx.Product.ToArray();
           }
   }



   Product[] ps = ModelAdapter.GetProducts();
   // ...
   ModelAdapter.UpdateProduct(p);
   ```

   - looks neat;
   - but, context is created/released a lot sometimes, objects lose contact with context;
2. Using context in place:

   ```
   using(Entities ctx = new Entities())
   {
           Product[] ps = ctx.Product.ToArray();

           // ...

           ctx.SaveChanges();
   }
   ```

   - effective
   - but, code becomes messy
3. Mixed mode, compromise?
4. Extension methods:

   ```
   using(Entities ctx = new Entities())
   {
       Product[] ps = ctx.GetProducts();
       // ...
       ctx.UpdateProduct(p);
   }
   ```

Actually now, I'm trying approach #4, implementing utility methods as extensions to context. So I can use one context, and make many calls to this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally use anything that fits your needs, that is maintainable and that fits to the complexity of your application. Few points which you should think about:

- [Never share context among requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653009/entity-framework-and-connection-pooling/3653392#3653392), use a context per request, per action or per method depending on your needs.
- If you want to unit test your application you can find that static methods and sometimes also extension methods can be a problem. But testing application with EF is [a separate problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609508/asp-net-mvc3-and-entity-framework-code-first-architecture/5610685#5610685).
- If you want to modify or insert more items in a single unit of work you can find that a context per method is not what you need
- Many developers like to use the repository pattern to separate access to EF features from the rest of the application. It has its own [pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625746/generic-repository-with-ef-4-1-what-is-the-point/5626884#5626884).

Comment: Thanks @Ladislav! This definitely a good wrap up of a problem. A lot of useful info in and around you links.

Answer (score 6):

When developing web applications I've been using a shared context which is created per web request.  Then you can use your "ModelAdapter" approach and retain encapsulation but still operate on the same context. I've used this a lot and haven't experienced any problems.

Comment: Context per request is an excellent way to go unless you have some compelling reason to do otherwise. It keeps the design logically simple, too - 1:1 for request and EF context.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I would go for an implementation where the complexities of dealing with EF are abstracted away by using the [Repository pattern](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2008/04/24/what-purpose-does-the-repository-pattern-have.aspx), but have the context alive as long as I need it. (Scenario 3)

By "as long as I need it" I mean as long as the service call takes. I don't want the `ObjectContext` to persist through multiple service calls, as I would need to deal with its state. The cost of creating a new `ObjectContext` is negligible.

I think in many ways your `ModelAdapter` also abstracts away EF complexities, however based on its static nature, you might/will run into problems in concurrent scenarios if you decide to persist the `ObjectContext`. The way it's implemented now might not give you the flexibility you need for more complex queries (joining Order<->OrderDetail<->Product for instance).