# Inject DbContext in Asp.Net Core. Concrete type or interface?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

On an Asp.Net Core project I am injecting Entity Framework DbContext:

```
public MessageRepository(MyDbContext context) {
}
```

And the configuration is:

```
services
  .AddEntityFramework()
  .AddSqlServer()
  .AddDbContext<Context>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
```

Should I create an interface, IMyDbContext, and injecting it instead?

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext, IMyDbContext { }

public MessageRepository(IMyDbContext context) {
}
```

In all ASP.NET Core examples I see the concrete type, MyDbContext, is being injected and not an interface ...

What option should I choose?

Comment: At a point, you'll have to make some decision because you can't abstract anything (or you are going to loose so much time...). I consider that EF is part of my infrastructure components like Json.Net : If I have to move away from EF I am pretty sure this will be in a decade.... So don't overthink too much ^^ Good luck

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We're always injecting an interface, since it's easier to mock in unit and integration tests.

1. Are you willing to change the signature of the `MessageRepository` constructor? It relies on the concrete type.
2. Do you write tests for your code? Using and interface would make it easier to mock the database context.

If you've answered "no" to one or more of the above, inject the concrete type; otherwise, inject the interface.

**[EDIT]**
use the following.

```
context services.AddScoped<IApplicationDbContext>(provider => provider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how you register your repository interface? Do you use `AddDbContext` or `AddScoped`?

Comment: Add the dbcontext as you normally do using services.AddDbContext. and then register the service and implementation for the database context
 services.AddScoped<IApplicationDbContext>(provider => provider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>()); check the link https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/resolve-dbcontext-as-interface-in-aspnet5-ioc-container/

Answer (score 12):

Currently working on a project myself, where I decided to go with 2 interfaces like this

```
public interface IDbContext : IDisposable
{
    DbContext Instance { get; }
}
```

and

```
public interface IApplicationDbContext : IDbContext
{
    DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

My concrete DbContext would then just implement the application context interface

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext, IApplicationDbContext
{
    public DbContext Instance => this

    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
}
```

This allows my implementation of the Application context to be injected as the application context interface, while also providing me access to the DbContext methods through the Instance property getter without having to add methods needed from the DbContext class to the interface.

Until now, this works great.

Comment: Why not combine the two interfaces?

Comment: I really can't remember, think I had a reason.

Comment: This approach exposes all methods of the DBContext though they can rather be abstracted away through the use of a Repository pattern (in combination with a Unit of Work type)

Comment: @BernoulliIT yes, but injecting the context class directly would expose everything as well. This approach simply removes the work required to keep the injected interface up to date with the DbContext class methods and properties.

Comment: Thank you for saving my life. I needed exactly this. I had to access context.Entry() method and was not able to access it from interface (ofcourse).

Comment: For the record. The top interface IDbContext with the _Instance_ property is needed if you use a repository pattern and want to access your tables through Set<T>, e.g. `public T? Get( int id ) => myIDbContext.Instance.Set<T>().Find( id );`

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should always rely on an interface as @Uli said, but when it comes to the DbContext you need to take in mind that you are exposing all methods of the DbContext of EntityFramework Core

public class MyDbContext : **DbContext**, IMyDbContext { }

in that case, you don't need to implement any method that you are exposing because DbContext handles that for you.

BUT if EF code change the DbContext and you make an update to your project then you will be on a painful situation of updating your IMyDbContext every time, also all your unit testing. In my opinion, that will give you a lot of headaches.

This answers/questions can help you to understand why https://stackoverflow.com/a/6768712/819153

[Unit testing EF - how to extract EF code out from BL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10940873/819153)

Comment: Yes, but on the other hand, if you're adding functionality by changing the DbContext, you'll be updating your unit tests regardless if you're using an interface or not. Plus, if you just need tables, the interface would be just the DbSets for your underlying tables. It would only need updating when you're adding/removing tables and that's only a single line change per table.